# WiX: Component, Directory and CreateFolder tags, how to write Components

Tags: wix, windows-installer

i'm attempting to follow tutorials and guides to learn WiX and i'm not really understanding how all of these basic elements come together.  i'm attempting to package just a folder containing JRE6.  i'm generating the WiX XML with a little parser, but i'm not sure how this is actually supposed to look.

the goal is basically to package the entire JRE6 in the installation as a single Component.  i can't figure out the proper structure.  when i try this:

```
 <Directory Id="jre6_dir" Name="jre6">
      <Directory Id="dir_jre_jre6bin" Name="bin">
        <File Id="binawt.dll" Name="awt.dll" />
        <File Id="binaxbridge.dll" Name="axbridge.dll" />
        <Directory Id="dir_jre_binclient" Name="client">
          <File Id="clientclasses.jsa" Name="classes.jsa" />
          <File Id="clientjvm.dll" Name="jvm.dll" />
          <File Id="clientXusage.txt" Name="Xusage.txt" />
        </Directory>
 etc...
```

the compiler tells me that i can't place a File tag within a Directory tag.

so i have tried:

- placing `File` tags inside `Directory` tags.
- placing `File` tags inside `CreateFolder` tags.
- placing `Directory` tags inside the `Component` tag.

none of this works.  i'm just not understanding the very basics of how WiX works and how i should create a component like this.  i just want to be able to call the contents of the JRE6 directory its own Component in the installation.  how do i do this?

Comment: You should be using the "Heat.exe" wix tool to harvest files/directories for including in wix installers. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html

Comment: It works pretty well. I harvest a help directory in multiple languages with heat for one of the product installs I authored and that help directory has 2000+ files in it.

Comment: @BrianSutherland thx for the comment. i gave `heat` a try and it produced some craziness that had every subdirectory in its own `Fragment` tag. each `File` was placed in a single `Component` by itself. this is just ugly to look at and doesn't make much sense. isn't there a more sensible structure?

Comment: use -sfrag -suid cmd line options. Some other options may also be useful for you. You may need to not use -suid if you have files with the same name in different folders.